# how to wait untill end of effect? (i looked at duplicates)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so I have this site: http://webzilla-il.com/contactus.php , now i know it's not in english but the text isn't important what's important is the jquery, try click on each image on the purple area, as you can see a div slide's down with some texts, now try clicking fast on the images one after another, the divs are showing before the sliding up has finished and making it look bad...

My code so far is:

```
//Contact us
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box").click(function(){
        var name = $(this).attr("name");
        $(".sform").slideUp().promise().done(function() {                   
            switch(name){
                case "skype":
                    $('.sform[name="'+name+'"]').next().promise().done(function() {$(this).css("margin-left","4px")});
                    $('.sform[name="'+name+'"]').slideDown();
                    break;
                case "form":
                    $('.sform[name="skype"]').next().promise().done(function() {$(this).css("margin-left","60px")});
                    $('.sform[name="'+name+'"]').slideDown();
                    break;
                case "email":
                    $('.sform[name="skype"]').next().promise().done(function() {$(this).css("margin-left","60px")});
                    $('.sform[name="'+name+'"]').slideDown();
                    break;
            }
        });             
    });
});
```

My html:

```
    <div id="contact_forms">
        <div class="cform sform" style="margin-left: 60px; display: none;" name="skype"> <!--Skype-->
            <div class="skypes">
            <h5><a class="cf" href="skype:londneramit">londneramit</a></h5>
                עמית לונדנר
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="skypes" name="skype">
                <h5><a class="cf" href="skype:dan_barzilay">dan_barzilay</a></h5>
                דן ברזילי   
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cform" style="margin-left: 60px; visibility: hidden;"></div> 

        <div class="cform sform" name="form"> <!--Form-->
            <div id="webzilla_contact_us" style="border: none;">
                <form method="POST" onsubmit="return contactUs(this)">
                    <input type="text" name="name" />
                    <input type="email" name="email" />
                    <input type="text" name="title" />
                    <br style="clear: both;" />
                    <textarea name="content"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" name="contactsub" value="שלח!"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cform" style="visibility: hidden;"></div> 

        <div class="cform sform" style="display: none;" name="email"> <!--Email-->
            <h6><a class="cf" href="mailto:webzilla-il@gmail.com">webzilla-il@gmail.com</a></h6>
            <div id="breaker"><img src="img/Contact/shadow_breaker.png" alt="breaker" /></div>
            <div class="emails">
                <h5><a class="cf" href="mailto:londner.amit@gmail.com">londner.amit@gmail.com</a></h5>
                עמית לונדנר
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="emails">
                <h5><a class="cf" href="mailto:barzilaydn@gmail.com">barzilaydn@gmail.com</a></h5>
                דן ברזילי                   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see i have tryed promise().done()...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you need something like clear the animation queue and finish all current animation then execute the click event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something more simple,

is this what u are trying to reach?

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/d96JQ/20/)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

```
 $('.sform').not(":visible").slideUp(function() {
            // will be called when the element finishes fading out
            // if selector matches multiple elements it will be called once for each
            switch(name){
                    case "skype":
                        $('.sform[name="'+name+'"]').next().promise().done(function() {$(this).css("margin-left","4px")});
                        $('.sform[name="'+name+'"]').slideDown();
                        break;
                    case "form":
                        $('.sform[name="skype"]').next().promise().done(function() {$(this).css("margin-left","60px")});
                        $('.sform[name="'+name+'"]').slideDown();
                        break;
                    case "email":
                        $('.sform[name="skype"]').next().promise().done(function() {$(this).css("margin-left","60px")});
                        $('.sform[name="'+name+'"]').slideDown();
                        break;
                }

        });
```

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

Comment: wouldn't this cause the thing to slide up and down for as many times a you clicked? even though it would queue them but they will all display wouldn't they?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".sform").stop(true, true).slideUp().promise().done(..)
```

This may give some luck:

```
$(".sform:animated").slideUp(100).promise().done(..)
```

oR

```
$(".sform:animated").slideUp(100, function() {
  switch(name) {...}
})
```

You may check with out `duration`

Comment: You may want to use .stop(true, true) so it will return to the original position.

Comment: play around with the stop(), it should work, try setting the true to false and have different combos. Don't expect everyone to spoon feed you

Answer (score 0):

My work firewall isn't letting me see your website for some reason, but looking at your code, you might be able to try using the callback of instead:

```
$(".sform").slideUp(function() {                   
    switch(name){
        case "skype":
            $('.sform[name="'+name+'"]').next().promise().done(function() {$(this).css("margin-left","4px")});
            $('.sform[name="'+name+'"]').slideDown();
            break;
        case "form":
            $('.sform[name="skype"]').next().promise().done(function() {$(this).css("margin-left","60px")});
            $('.sform[name="'+name+'"]').slideDown();
            break;
        case "email":
            $('.sform[name="skype"]').next().promise().done(function() {$(this).css("margin-left","60px")});
            $('.sform[name="'+name+'"]').slideDown();
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Did it have the same behaviour or something different?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are calling SlideUp to ALL of the boxes every time you click on any of them.

```
$(".sform").not(":visible").slideUp().promise().done(function() {      

...
```